# Single Query to fetch all records from hierarchical table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I have a hierarchical table for threaded comments for a blog post from which I need to fetch a set of records based on the given query filters.
The table structure is like this

```
ID, PARENTID, APPROVEDSTATUS, COMMENTSTATUS, COMMENTORID, MODERATORID....
```

The first comment for a blog will have parentid = 0. The comment goes through a moderation process where moderator (can be blog owner) can highlight the comment for other moderators to review or they can respond to it. The com mentor can then respond back to any reply from the blog owner and then chain can go on.

I need to display the listing of all comments for all blogs in java run page. The page allows the user to filter the displayed records based on commentstatus, star rating for that blog, no of votes for that comment etc. Some of these filters apply to the main comment and some apply on each child level.
How I went about this initially was I the first level of comments and iterate over each to see the children and children of children so that its easy to display in the threaded format. 
The problem comes when applying the filter. When I apply the filter on the main level for example where commentstatus is 'highlighted' comments, this will return 0 records as this status is at the child level. Similarly star rating is at the parent level. 
Is there a way I can fetch all the records and apply the filter conditions and have then in the correct order.

```
PRIMARY QUERY: 

    select id, parentid, approvedstatus, 
           commentstatus, personname, 
           actiontime 
     from v_comment_tree where parentCommentid=0;

QUERY 2:

select id, parentid, approvedstatus, commentstatus, 
       personname, actiontime 
  from v_comment_tree 
 where parentCommentid=40611 
   and commentstatus = 'flag';
```

Query 2 is fired by passing id from first comment.

[Java Portion]

```
public CommentList getBlogComments(){
  /* get the filters from the request if any and built where clause.
     On loading first time there will be no filters*/
   filter1 = " and commentstatus = 'flag'"; 
   filter2 = " and rate = 5";
   /* execute the query by adding these filters to the original query and iterate over the loop and add the result to the CommentList. 
      This is the parentid. */
   /* check if this id has children. For this I call another function passing this id */
     getSubBlogComments(id, filter1+filter2);

   return CommentList;
}

private void getSubBlogComments(id, String filters){
   /* here I execute Query 2 by applying the same filter 
   and iterate over the loop and add the result to the CommentList. 
      This is the parentid. */
   /* check if this id has children. With this I again call this function passing this id */

     getSubBlogComments(id, filters);

}
```

The issue arises when because of applying filters at the first query returns me no results and so I cannot get the results from the child where there could be a record with flagged status. If there was a single query that would fetch the parent child records in the correct order and apply the filter over the whole result. Even then, there is this problem. If i get the child record I need to get the original parent and display the whole thread based on that child record. Should I write a procedure?

Comment: Can you please post your relevant code?

Comment: Do you want the java code? or the sql query?

Comment: I think that the Java code would be good since you are doing all the job there.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a series of anonymous views 'allcomments' will get the list of comments in the thread starting at the root node. I think it is better to have it done in the sql than in java as it is easy to do it this way.

```
--this will get all the comments in the thread starting at parent = 0
with allcomments as 
  (select 
     id, parentid, approvedstatus, commentstatus, personname, actiontime
   from v_comment_tree
   start with
     parentCommentid=0 
   connect by prior id = parentCommentid)
select * from allcomments where <your filter conditions here>
```